# MATLAB interp2 function in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, linear-algebra, interpolation

I need a Python equivalent to the **interp2** MATLAB's function. I am trying to make this [MATLAB example](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html) working in Python but I can't.

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

service = np.array(range(10, 31, 10))
years = np.array(range(1950, 1991, 10))

wage = np.array([[150.6970,199.5920,187.6250],
    [179.3230, 195.0720, 250.2870],
    [203.2120, 179.0920, 322.7670],
    [226.5050, 153.7060, 426.7300],
    [249.6330, 120.2810, 598.2430]])

ip = RectBivariateSpline(years, service, wage)

print(ip(15, 1975))
```

But I get this error (in RectBivariateSpline) which I can't solve:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrea/Documents/workspace/PythonProjects/pyArmBot/src/foo.py", line 15, in <module>
    ip = RectBivariateSpline(years, service, wage)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.10.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 728, in __init__
    kx,ky,s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to be calling ip to return a value by using the following line instead of your print line.

`print(ip.ev(15, 1975))`

Update:

Pretty easy tweak.  And was staring my in the face.  You can set the value of kx and ky, which are the degrees of the bivariate spline [See documentation here](http://gaezipserver.appspot.com/python/sci/scipy/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html)

Anyway, just adjust the line to be:

`ip = RectBivariateSpline(years, service, wage, kx=2, ky=2)`

You don't need to adjust kx if you don't want to.  I doubt it will change the interpolation much if you leave kx as 3.

Comment: Ok I see that now that I plugged your code into python on my end.  It would be a better if you included the whole traceback next time when the error is thrown.  I'll take a gander here again in a little bit.

Comment: No worries.  I tossed an update in my answer that should hopefully fix ya up here.

Comment: it works in fact but why? Anyway the result (160.12) is different to the one in MATLAB (190.6288) I imagine it has to. Or not?

Comment: Try using 'cubic' as the modifier in matlab's interp2 function and I bet you get right around 160.12

Answer (score 0):

blueSurfer, I think the way you have set up your interpolation, the correct results will be obtained by `ip(1975, 15)` and not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, and figured out that `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` does the same as `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)`. Please read the documentation of these commands to find out the solution for your case.

Try this for Matlab's `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)` :

```
Vq = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(V, [Xq.ravel(), Yq.ravel()], order=3, mode='nearest').reshape(V.shape)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remove the link and improve your answer to contain the information that would be contained in that link, even if it is one of your own answers. Please do so on the answer linked as well.

Comment: Hi Antoine thank you for your reminder! Please try this solution, I hope it helps for your problem!